# CUDA Matrix Multiplication Shared Memory Bank Conflicts

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I am trying to do a matrix multiplication using CUDA and shared memory. Unfortunately I get Bank Conflicts for matrixes where height and width > 128. For matrixes with height and width <= 128, I get 0 Bank Conflicts. (Nsight Compute)

```
#define SHMEM_SIZE (16 * 16)

__global__ void matMulKernelSharedMemory(float *matrixA, float *matrixB, float *matrixC, int dimSize)
{

    __shared__ float s_matrixA[SHMEM_SIZE];
    __shared__ float s_matrixB[SHMEM_SIZE];

    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;
    int dim = blockDim.x;

    float value = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < ((dimSize + dim - 1) / dim); i++)
    {
        s_matrixA[ty * dim + tx] = matrixA[(row * dimSize) + (i * dim) + tx];
        s_matrixB[ty * dim + tx] = matrixB[(i * dim * dimSize) + (ty * dimSize) + col];
        __syncthreads();

        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
        {
            value += s_matrixA[ty * dim + j] * s_matrixB[j * dim + tx];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    matrixC[row * dimSize + col] = value;
}
```

I am using the following dimensions:

```
int threads = 16;
int blocks = (dimSize + threads - 1) / threads;
dim3 dimGrid(blocks, blocks);
dim3 dimBlock(threads, threads);
```

The GPU is a A4000. The max size of the input matrixes is 4096 * 4096.

I tried to use 32 * 32 shared memory but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Incorrect results? Launch failure? Works, but still bank conflicts?

Comment: I think you get bank conflicts for small matrices as well. Profiling small kernels does not work well as the profiler (Nsight Compute) needs enough active SMs to collect data. It can show you which accesses produce conflicts in the [Source View](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/NsightCompute/index.html#profiler-report-source-page) as "L1 Wavefronts Shared Excessive".

Comment: The calculation works, but I still get bank conflicts.

Comment: Nsight compute has difficulty in reporting shared memory bank conflicts correctly.  As one example, note comment from Greg [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/shared-memory-bank-conflicts-and-nsight-metric/115731/6): " I can confirm that on Turing the hardware counter report additional unexpected bank conflicts."  I don't believe your code is generating any actual bank conflicts, or stated another way, there is nothing you can do to further reduce bank conflicts in your posted code.

Comment: Also note [additional statement from greg](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/shared-memory-bank-conflicts-and-nsight-metric/115731/14): "There is not currently a hardware counter that only counts bank conflicts. Other arbitration conflicts that result in a replayed wavefront are included. Summing L1 Wavefronts Shared Excessive on the Source View page is the best method to only count bank conflicts. The L1 Wavefronts Shared Ideal accounts for additional wavefronts for wider data types (e.g. 64b or 128b)."